# How do I ORDER BY MAX(date) in a subquery in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, subquery

I'm in trouble with this query :

I have two tables : samples and songs
I would like to select

```
pathName   from samples
id_user    from samples
id         from songs
name       from songs
```

Each sample belongs to a song : I would like to group every samples sharing the same song id in order to select the last in date.
so i make a join between the two tables like this :

```
$query = 'SELECT 
            samples.pathName path_name,
            samples.id_user id_user,
            songs.id id_song,
            songs.name song_name
        FROM (SELECT *, MAX(date) AS maxDate FROM samples GROUP BY id_song ORDER BY maxDate) samples
        INNER JOIN songs songs
        ON songs.id = samples.id_chanson
        WHERE songs.finished = false';
```

It should not be so heavy, I hope I'm clear ... :)

Comment: What you are doing (ORDER BY in a derived table, then GROUP BY in the external query), you shouldn't be doing. See **[GROUP BY trick has been optimized away](https://kb.askmonty.org/en/group-by-trick-has-been-optimized-away/)**

Comment: Though seems you find the answer, but usually I use VIEW, it make little better to read too.

Comment: I specifically avoided using this technique in my answer for the reason ypercube raised. It should continue to work in current versions of MySQL (though not MariaDB, as linked), but is not guaranteed to work in future versions of MySQL.

Comment: Oh okay, i'm a bit lost with all of those things, i'm brand new with MySQL, and I have to finish a project in a few days, I'm just glad it's kinda working for now, but I'll listen to you for the future!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
SELECT sa.pathName,
       sa.id_user,
       so.id id_song,
       so.name song_name
FROM songs so
JOIN (SELECT id_song, MAX(`date`) AS maxDate FROM samples GROUP BY id_song) mx
  ON so.id = mx.id_song
JOIN samples sa 
  on mx.id_song = sa.id_song and mx.maxDate = sa.`date`
WHERE so.finished = 'false'
ORDER BY mx.maxDate
```

Comment: hi! :) it looks like it's not working but this is helping thanks!

Comment: @PomponPasFrais: In what way is it not working? Is it returning an error? Are no records being returned? Are multiple records being returned for the same song? Does it look like the wrong sample (ie. not the most recent) is being returned for a specific song?

Comment: I got my answer, your code was not returning anything but i was probably wrong and not so clear with myself, i think everything is fine now, thanks again!! :)

Comment: Mark, your query is correct but (based on the horrendous query in the last OP edit), I think the `so.finished = 'false'` needs to be in the subquery, too (with one more JOIN to `songs`, inside there).

Comment: @ypercube: Leaving the `so.finished = 'false'` out of the subquery shouldn't affect the functionality of the overall query since the filtering will be done as part of the main query - there's an inner join to songs, so only unfinished songs should be selected. It may have an impact on performance, but without further information I don't know what that impact would be.

Comment: @PomponPasFrais: It returns rows when I try it with test data: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c6945/1

Comment: okay.jpg, I'm sorry then, I'll try to optimize my code later, for now i keep my stuff :)

Comment: @Mark: My bad, you are right. Your query should give the expected output.

Comment: OKAY it's working you're kinda kind guys I kiss you everywhere

Answer (score 0):

I would use something like this:

```
SELECT
  samples.pathName path_name,
  samples.id_user id_user,
  songs.id id_song,
  songs.name song_name
FROM
  samples INNER JOIN songs ON songs.id = samples.id_song
WHERE
  songs.finished = false
  AND (samples.id_song, samples.`date`) IN (SELECT   id_song, MAX(`date`)
                                            FROM     samples
                                            GROUP BY id_song)
```